# Get next item from an array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Given a string column that represents a path (`'/11/22/33/44'`), how do I return the next number after the given one.

For example:

- given an id=`22`, I want to return `33` from the path `/11/22/33/44/`.
- given an id=`44`, I want to return `NULL` from the path `/11/22/33/44/`.

This is the bit I use to convert the string into a set of records:

```
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(trim(both '/' from '/11/22/33/44/'), '/')::integer[]);
 unnest 
--------
     11
     22
     33
     44
(4 rows)
```

But how to obtain the "next entry" here (so given `22` -> `33`)?

Comment: I presume the numbers are unique within a given path?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it would be possible to enforce that if no better solution would be available.

Comment: Normally, keeping data in a string field with a separator is not the way to go in a database. Instead, I would keep a table of paths, with a pointer to the parent for each path, or something along those lines.

Comment: @perh yes, I agree 100% but for the time being it is the simplest solution. I'll definitely migrate to a separate table or just a normal array. But the same question would still stand.

Comment: If you don't have unique numbers in the group then you can't find the "next" because there are multiple possible answers. You need an index into the array instead.

Comment: @CraigRinger with multiple same values it should be the first one. So that `/11/22/22/33/` and `22` as an input it should return `22`. But that's more of an edge case that I don't care too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is a window function:

```
SELECT a FROM (
    SELECT *, lag(a) OVER () AS lag_1
    FROM unnest(string_to_array(trim(both '/' from '/11/22/33/44/'), '/')::integer[]) a
) b WHERE lag_1 = 22;
```

This solution returns zero rows for the `44` input, but that's easily addressed by invoking it as a subquery.

Alternately, for integer arrays you can use the [intarray extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html)'s `idx` function:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;

WITH x(arr) AS (
    SELECT string_to_array(trim(both '/' from '/11/22/33/44/'), '/') :: integer[]
)
SELECT arr[idx(arr,22)+1] FROM x;
```

to look up the next index in the array. `intarray` is an extension distributed with PostgreSQL, it's not a 3rd party add-on. This solution produces a `NULL` result for `44` without further manipulation.

Comment: There you go - `leg` function! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DmytriiNagirniak Alternate array-based solution added

Comment: Thanks array functions would be better since I won't need to `unnest`, but don't want to add an extension to the DB.

Comment: @DmytriiNagirniak I hear that a lot I and I don't get it. It's a core part of PostgreSQL, it's just not active by default. Why don't you want to add it?

Comment: Every time I add an extension I feel like I have another dependency to worry about. I prefer not to introduce another dependency if I can go along without it. But, I guess you're right. No reason NOT to add that since it is not really a dependency.

Comment: @CraigRinger are array functions you are talking about an extension ?

Comment: @greg See the link in the answer. It's a contrib module, which is part of the main PostgreSQL distribution. It's packaged as an extension module that's activated with `CREATE EXTENSION`. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html